# Want to write a shell to rename multi-files

Tags: shell, unix

Here is what my filenames look like:

```
1. Two Sum.cpp
2. xxx xxx.cpp
```

I want to change the filenames like this:

```
P1-Two-Sum.cpp
P2-xxx-xxx.cpp
```

remove the dot "`.`" behind Number

replace ""  with "`-`",

then add prefix "`P`";

but I'm not familiar with shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`bash` *parameter substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for f in *.cpp ; do d="${f/.}" ; mv "$f" "P${d// /-}" ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the `rename` command, a.k.a. **Perl rename**. Then you could do:

```
rename --dry-run 's|^(\d+)[. ]+(.*)|P$1 $2|; s| |-|g' *cpp
```

**Sample Output**

```
'1. Two Sum.cpp' would be renamed to 'P1-Two-Sum.cpp'
'21. Merge Two Sorted Lists.cpp' would be renamed to 'P21-Merge-Two-Sorted-Lists.cpp'
'4. Median of Two Sorted Arrays.cpp' would be renamed to 'P4-Median-of-Two-Sorted-Arrays.cpp'
```

If that looks correct, make a backup, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again.

The command says... *"Rename all files ending in `.cpp` as follows. Capture any number of digits (`\d+`) at the start of the line (`^`) as capture group 1. Allow, and ignore any number of spaces or dots (`[. ]+`). Capture the rest of the line as capture group 2. Replace the filename with a `P` followed by capture group 1, then a space, then capture group 2. Finally, replace globally, all instances of a space with a dash."*.

If you are not used to Perl, there are two substitution statements in there, so from 20,000 feet it says:

```
substitute|something|something else|  ;  substitute|something|something else|
```